# Focusing to the .next() td textbox in a table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I want to be able to press tab once the `.editbox` is clicked and it take the `focus` to the next `.editbox`. I have been messing with the code for an hour now and cannot "find" the next element.

Here is my code to do it. For help you will likely need more context. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkNny/) to elaborate on what I am dealing with.

```
//on tab
        $(".edit_tr").on('keydown', '.editbox', function(e) { 
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

            if (keyCode == 9) { 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var focus = $(document.activeElement);
                //console.log(focus);
                focus.closest('td').siblings('.editbox').focus();
                console.log(focus.parent().next('.editbox'));
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line #41 you have to go with:

```
focus.closest('td').next().find(".editbox").show().focus();
```

This will go back to the current `td`, look for the following `td` tag, search for .editbox and before you can focus() on it you have to show() it (make it visible) first.

This solution will only work for 1 line. If you want to move between different lines with the tab key you'll have to do the following:

```
var nextEditbox = focus.closest('td').next().find(".editbox");
//check if there are still .editboxes on the same line
if(nextEditbox.length){
    //go for it and focus the next edit box on the same line
    nextEditbox.show().focus();
}
else {
    //move to the next line and search for the next editbox
    nextEditbox = focus.closest('tr').next().find(".edit_td:first").find(".editbox");

    //show and focus
    nextEditbox.show().focus();
}

//this will end the focusing and the .change() (which is defined above) will fire and do the ajax
focus.blur();
```

You'll have to do the hiding of the .text elements yourself.

Edit: Here's the Savebutton-Solution. I didn't test it, but I think it should work.

```
var changes = [];
$(".editbox").change(function(){
   changes.push({ id : $(this).attr("id"), changed : $(this).attr("name"), data : $(this).val() });
});

$(".savebutton").click(function(){
   //AJAX SENDING THE changes VAR TO THE PHP FILE
});
```

Comment: All seems to be working well. Thanks a lot for that. I now will want to have a `SAVE` button on the page. Previously I had an AJAX call POST to the database once a textbox was changed. Any references to sending an unknown number of POST data back to the server to an update query?

Comment: I see. I am reloading the entire page after the request so it won't work. :/ I'd much rather just have it able to post all the data back at once on a button click or something. I just never really learned how to do that.

Comment: @user2690363 Then you should make an array and track the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
$(".edit_tr").on('keydown', '.editbox', function(e) {
```

Should be

```
$(".edit_td").on('keydown', '.editbox', function(e) {
```

Besides, [JQuery editTable](http://codeb.it/edittable/) may meets your requirements.

Comment: It does. The 3rd example is what I am trying to do. I just do not know how to go about loading my data into it. I loading it via PHP. It is not static. The Fiddle was just an example.